# How do I Mock MongoDB Data Access Layer using Repository Pattern?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I want to Test the Method `FindAsync(Expression<Func>)` from the MongoDB C# Driver. My goal is it to
test my expression, I don't want to Mock the FindAsync Method itself. In EF I would Mock the DB Set and return my own Enumerator which is filled with my IEnumerable with test data. Can I do something like that in MongoDB also?

I using the Driver Version 2.10.4
And the Framework Moq 4.14.5

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have here is `FindAsync(Expression<Func>)` is an extention method that just creates a new `ExpressionFilterDefinition` with your expression and passes it on.

```cs
Expression<Func<TDocument, bool>> filter = // some expression.

collection.FindAsync(new ExpressionFilterDefinition<TDocument>(filter), options, cancellationToken);
```

So you'll need to mock out the following method on `IMongoCollection<TDocument>`

```cs
public override Task<IAsyncCursor<TProjection>> FindAsync<TProjection>(
      FilterDefinition<TDocument> filter,
      FindOptions<TDocument, TProjection> options,
      CancellationToken cancellationToken = default (CancellationToken));
```

Here's a quick example using Moq

```cs
var list = new List<Class>
{
    new Class {Id = "1", Name = "Name1"},
    new Class {Id = "2", Name = "Name2"},
    new Class {Id = "3", Name = "Name3"}
};

var collection = new Mock<IMongoCollection<Class>>();
collection.Setup(x => x.FindAsync<Class>(
    It.IsAny<FilterDefinition<Class>>(),
    It.IsAny<FindOptions<Class, Class>>(),
    It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()
)).ReturnsAsync((FilterDefinition<Class> filter,
    FindOptions<Class, Class> options,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken) =>
{
    // We'll need to get back the expression 
    var expressionFilter = (ExpressionFilterDefinition<Class>)filter;

    // Filtered our mocked list
    var filtererList = list.Where(expressionFilter.Expression.Compile())
        .ToList();

    // Return a stubbed cursor with our filtered list
    return new StubAsyncCursor<Class>(filtererList) as IAsyncCursor<Class>;
});


var cursor = await collection.Object.FindAsync(x => x.Id == "2");

var result = await cursor.ToListAsync();

foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine($@"Id: {item.Id}, Name: {item.Name}");
}

// Output
// Id: 2, Name: Name2
```

```cs
public class StubAsyncCursor<T> : IAsyncCursor<T>
{
    private bool _disposed;
    private bool _moved;
    private readonly ICollection<T> _current;

    public StubAsyncCursor(ICollection<T> current)
    {
        this._current = current;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Current
    {
        get
        {
            this.ThrowIfDisposed();
            if (!this._moved)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Must call MoveNextAsync first");
            return this._current;
        }
    }

    public bool MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        this.ThrowIfDisposed();
        if (this._moved)
            return false;
        this._moved = true;
        return true;
    }

    public Task<bool> MoveNextAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        this.ThrowIfDisposed();
        return Task.FromResult<bool>(this.MoveNext(cancellationToken));
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this._disposed = true;
    }

    private void ThrowIfDisposed()
    {
        if (this._disposed)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(this.GetType().Name);
    }
}

public class Class
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Even though this is possible, this will only work when using an expression filter definition, I'd personally recommend just spinning up a local MongoDB instance, It's fast, simple and will prove all your queries work as they do in production.

```sh
docker run -d -p 27017:27107
```